# Trying to sign a jwt returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm learning node and I'm migrating my current API from python. I'm trying to create a jwt token to authenticate in a third party API, however my function returns `undefined`. The jwt method I'm using to sign the token is `async`, so I guess my function doesn't wait until jwt returns the token.

This is my function to sign and create the jwt token:

```
function token() {
  const payload = {
    iat: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000),
    exp: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + 30,
    sub: "api_key_jwt",
    iss: "external",
    jti: crypto.randomBytes(6).toString("hex")
  };
  return jwt.sign(payload, privatekey, { algorithm: "RS256" }, function(
    err,
    token2
  ) {
    return token2;
  });
}
```

So, when I call it:

```
exports.genToken = function() {
  const header = {
    "x-api-key": api
  };
  const data = {
    kid: api,
    jwt_token: token()
  };

  async function authorization(req, res) {
    try {
      const auth = await rp({
        url: authurl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: header,
        body: data
      });
      res.send(auth.body);
    } catch (error) {
      res.send(404).send();
    }
  }

  return {
    "x-api-key": api,
    Authorization: "Bearer " + authorization()
  };
};
```

`jwt_token` returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance guys!

Edit: `console.log(token2)` returns the signed token. So the problem is returning the token from the `token()` function

Comment: Can you console.log the err variable in the callback function and post it's results? Does it contain an error?

Comment: Hi George, I edited the question. Actually the token is being signed by the `jwt.sign`, however it doesn't return to the `token()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to return from a `callback` which doesn't work. Change your token function to return `Promise` then you can use the `async/await` like:

```
function token() {
  ...

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign(payload, privatekey, { algorithm: "RS256" }, function(err, token2) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(token2)
    });
  })
}

// note async
exports.genToken = async function() {
  ...
  const data = {
    kid: api,
    jwt_token: await token()
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: An addition to this correct answer: There are different implementations of async tasks in javascript. In your case, jwt library is not returning a promise, that's why you have to create your own promise to use it in your async/await approach. P.S: You could also take a callback function in your token and achieve the same thing.

Comment: Perfect! That was it. I still get a little bit confused with `async/await`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stackoverflow makes me wait 15 minutes before being able to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the catch if you supply  jwt.sign with the callback function it will work in async mode and going to return undefined so just omit the callback and it will work
your function will look like

```
function token() {
  const payload = {
    iat: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000),
    exp: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000) + 30,
    sub: "api_key_jwt",
    iss: "external",
    jti: crypto.randomBytes(6).toString("hex")
  };
  return jwt.sign(payload, privatekey, { algorithm: "RS256" });
}
```